# how to print params to a text file (log) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method in my controller

```
def mylovelyhaus
    @haus = Hause.find(params[:id])
end
```

I need to print the current params(id) in a text file (so log to a text file of the current id value everytime this method is called).
Tried to look for some stuffs in google, but not yet founded. How can I do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the Rails logger. It logs into `log/development.log`, `log/production.log` etc. It has five log levels (`debug`, `info`, `warn`, `error`, and `fatal`). Use it like this:

```
def mylovelyhaus
    logger.info(params[:id])
    @haus = Hause.find(params[:id])
end
```

But in development mode Rails logs the params to `log/development.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
logger.info "#{Time.now.strftime("[%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S]")} METHOD: #{File.basename(\__FILE__)}-->#{\__method__} ; PARAMETERS: #{params}"
```

This command will print current time, followed by FileName-->MethodName and than all the parameters available in that method.